# How do I calibrate rotated images with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Picture:

[image: picture]

A normal picture:

1. consists of three hexagons and a row of numbers, while an abnormal
   picture.
2. and 3. may be rotated at various angles.

I want to correct all the images to look like (1). In other words, let the row of numbers not rotate. How do I do this using OpenCv?

Comment: Based on hexagons, number of candidates of correction(rotate) result is only 3. So, select the best one based on your evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been helpful if you would have provided your approach(code segment) where you are stuck.

You can use tesseract library to correct the rotation of text by detecting text orientation using function:

> pytesseract.image_to_osd(rgb_image, output_type)

You can rotate the image using function:

> imutils.rotate_bound(image, angle)

You can refer to [this blog](https://pyimagesearch.com/2022/01/31/correcting-text-orientation-with-tesseract-and-python/) for more help.